# Navigation menu changes are not reflecting in Android salesfoce1 app

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am very new to salesforce1 and following the developer guide but when I change the navigation menu ,it is not reflecting with new changes in android salesforce1 app.

Please help me so that I can move ahead.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using Chatter Mobile 3.4 instead of Salesforce1. What happens is that when you download Salesforce1 from Google Play Store and you have a version of Android older than 4.2 you get a revamped version of Chatter Mobile 3.4 instead of Salesforce1. They even say this on the description on Google Play Store.

> Note:
>   The latest version of Salesforce1 requires devices with Android OS 4.2 (Jelly Bean) or later. Devices with Android OS 4.1 or earlier will receive Chatter Mobile 3.4

Try using the mobile web version instead

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested adding a new item to the menu and accessing Salesforce1 via my Nexus 7 with Android 4.4 and its working correctly. Also, there are no known issues of this type reported.

Have you confirmed that the item is in the Selected list on the Mobile Navigation setup page?  Also, if it is a Visualforce page, does the user you login through the Salesforce1 application as have access to the page?

When you change the navigation menu you have to then "refresh" the applications view of it by dragging the menu down, at which point you will see a "Release to refresh" message at the top.  Once you let go, the menu will be recreated from the Salesforce configuration.

If that doesn't work you could try restarting the Salesforce1 application - it would have to refresh the configuration at that point as it doesn't store anything on the device.

Comment: I am using salesforce1 downloadable app available in Google play store.Reflection of the changes is perfect in browser of the mobile. But it is not reflecting in the downloadable app.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  Everything I wrote above is based on the installable android application, which is working fine for me.  If its not working for you, I suggest you raise a case with Salesforce.

Comment: In my mobile it is still work like chatter because my phone's android version is 4.0 . I have to purchase new Phone.